# how to solve error mysql shutdown unexpectedly in xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

text in mysql_error.log is

```
2018-10-06 19:56:10 18bc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 20.0M
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2018-10-06 19:56:10 6332 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: Seems like your database files are corrupted. Try restarting MySQL. If still does not work, you may have to reinstall it

Comment: i try to restarting my sql but not solve :( please help me bro because when i reinstalling all database will be lost :(

Comment: Try connecting to mysql via terminal using `mysql -hlocalhost -uusername -ppassword` and check whether it is happening or not. I would suggest take a dump of your databases using `mysqldump` and reinstall it.

Comment: try add [mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1

Comment: but not working :(